# How can we track historical valuations of factor portfolios in emerging markets (in terms of P/B or P/E e.g.)?

Tags: equities, market-data, valuation, factor-investing

We can analyze factor investment approaches (momentum, low vol, quality, dividend, ...) for example by looking at the corresponding MSCI indices. Doing so we can read of today's valuations (P/E, Dividend Yield, ...).

Where can I find a source of a report for historical comparisons of these numbers (to be concrete: P/B or P/E)? My question focuses on EM but Global DM and Europe are also interesting.